# Fusing the two images in matlab based on location

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two images. Image A [image: imageA] and segmented mask Image B [image: ImageB].

I want to overlay a certain object in B over image A. I am able to do that in MATLAB using imfuse(A,B). But i want to overlay the object in image B over A using the certain location of A. For example, I want to overlay B over A from the certain distance above from bottom of image A. Right now it's random.

Code:

```
Original_image =imread('ImageA.jpeg');
Original_image =im2single(Original_image);
img = imread('ImageB.png');
S = regionprops((img>0),'BoundingBox');
a =round(S(1).BoundingBox(2));
b =round(S(1).BoundingBox(2)+S(1).BoundingBox(4));
c =round(S(1).BoundingBox(1));
d =round(S(1).BoundingBox(1)+S(1).BoundingBox(3));
img =img(a:b,c:d);
threhsold =1;
binary =(img==threhsold);
Overlay_image =imfuse(binary,Original_image,'diff');
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided sample images and your code.

Comment: @beaker Updated my question with images and code

Comment: Documentation: *If A and B are different sizes, imfuse pads the smaller dimensions with zeros so that both images are the same size before creating the composite*. So you can use `padarray` to pad them yourself and control the location. E.g. adding more zeros at the left border of the binary image moves it to the right.